# How to pass many forms to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

In my project I have multiple forms on same page which I want to pass in one go to controller.
How to achieve that?

```
<script>
function onSaveButtonClicked() {
    var form = $("#SaveForm").serialize();
    var form2 = $("#SaveForm").serialize();


    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Filter","SearcherEngine")',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ model: form, model2: form2 }),
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });

};
```

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Filter(MyViewMOdel model,MyViewModel2 model2)
{
}
```

Comment: Can't you wrap them up, both  the classes, into a single one?

Comment: I guess that, instead of calling serialize() to obtain strings, you should have your form and form2 as json objects. See : http://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/1236044

Comment: Nope,they are on separate tabs (demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/tabstrip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I joined both models in one, and wrapped partial views around one form.

```
class MyModel
{
   ...
}

    @model MyModel;
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
         Html.RenderPartial("Path",Model);
         Html.RenderPartial("Path",Model);   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

What makes this complex is the different view models per form. As a result, you cannot simply use an array and map to a list of a common class.

Keep in mind that model binding is done based on the structure of the object passed (posted in this case). So what you need to do is create a model that can hold the structure of what you want to pass in c#, and then *also* create that same structure in javascript to pass in.

```
public class ViewModelSet
{
 public MyViewModel model1 { get; set; }
 public MyViewModel1 model2 { get; set; }
}
```

Now you need to recreate this structure **with the exact same naming for properties** in javascript

```
var form1 = ...;
var form2 = ...;

var modelSet = {};
modelSet.model1 = form1;
modelSet.model2 = form2;
```

Next pass this in (only the name of the parameter must match the name of the expected parameter server side)

```
data: { model : modelSet },
```

And expect this to be passed server side

```
public ActionResult FilterNCTS(ViewModelSet model)
{
  //Now you should be able to have access to nested models
  // TODO: work with model.model1
  ...
}
```